# Pandas : How to add a list as an element to a single cell in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list `a` and DataFrame `dfdf`

I'm trying to add my list `a` to 1 cell of my DataFrame `dfdf`

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd 

b = [
    ['andy', 1, 10],
    ['bob', 2, 20],
    ['charlie', 3, 30]
] 
dfdf = pd.DataFrame(b)

dfdf.columns = ['Name', 'Number', 'Age']
dfdf['Place'] = ''
dfdf = dfdf.astype(object)

a = [1,2,3]
dfdf.loc[0,'Place'] = a
```

However it returns an error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-134-dcf87d474721> in <module>
      1 a = [1,2,3]
----> 2 dfdf.loc[0,'Place'] = a

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    690 
    691         iloc = self if self.name == "iloc" else self.obj.iloc
--> 692         iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)
    693 
    694     def _validate_key(self, key, axis: int):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value, name)
   1633         if take_split_path:
   1634             # We have to operate column-wise
-> 1635             self._setitem_with_indexer_split_path(indexer, value, name)
   1636         else:
   1637             self._setitem_single_block(indexer, value, name)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer_split_path(self, indexer, value, name)
   1686                     return self._setitem_with_indexer((pi, info_axis[0]), value[0])
   1687 
-> 1688                 raise ValueError(
   1689                     "Must have equal len keys and value "
   1690                     "when setting with an iterable"

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

I'm trying to add it like this:

```
    name    number  age new
0   Andy    1       10  [1, 2]
1   Bob     2       20  50
2   Charlie 3       30  50
```

Can anybody help me for this problem? Thanks a lot

Comment: Works fine on Pandas 1.1.4 here.

Comment: pd.__version__ `1.2.0` raise this error too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code works fine and returns the following output, which is correct but different from what you listed as your expected output:

```
      Name Number Age      Place
0     andy      1  10  [1, 2, 3]
1      bob      2  20           
2  charlie      3  30
```

The key step was to change the type to object to allow insertion of a list into the existing dataframe, but you have already taken care of that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code ran on my computer producing the following table.

```
      Name Number Age      Place
0     andy      1  10  [1, 2, 3]
1      bob      2  20           
2  charlie      3  30
```

Just for completeness I went ahead and added that extra 50 in to so the result of this matches your desired output.

```py
b = [
    ['andy', 1, 10],
    ['bob', 2, 20],
    ['charlie', 3, 30]
] 
dfdf = pd.DataFrame(b)

dfdf.columns = ['Name', 'Number', 'Age']
dfdf['Place'] = 50
dfdf = dfdf.astype(object)

dfdf.loc[0,'Place'] = [1, 2]
```

Comment: yeah, i don't know why but I try not using .loc but using regular slicing (dfdf['Place'][0] = a) and it works. Thanks a lot for your answer